Whats the point of ICC warrants against Russia or Israel?
The International Criminal Court (ICC) issued arrest warrants against Russian officials and has an application for warrants against Israeli officials.  For the latter, Karim A. A. Khan states “my Office is acting pursuant to its mandate under the Rome Statute.”
But the ICC only has jurisdiction over countries that agree to the Rome Statute, which currently does not include Russia or Israel¹.  So it seems these actions are pointless, if not a violation of ICC’s charter.
Am I misinformed about something?
¹or USA

You are misinformed about ICC jurisdiction
The ICC has jurisdiction when:


the crimes were committed by a State Party national, or in the territory of a State Party, or in a State that has accepted the jurisdiction of the Court; or

the crimes were referred to the ICC Prosecutor by the United Nations Security Council (UNSC) pursuant to a resolution adopted under chapter VII of the UN charter.



Ukraine is a state party and the indicted Russians have committed crimes in her territory.
The ICC also has jurisdiction over crimes committed in Palestinian territory as well as over crimes committed by Palestinian nationals.

Ah, another version said "… by a person in the territory of …"  The crimes were certainly in Ukraine, but the criminals were in Russia.

Tiny technicality: allegedly have commited crimes. That crimes happened is sure, that those people are responsible has to still be proven in a court of law. Though I don't believe that those people are innocent we have to presume then innocent till proven guilty.


What's the point of ICC warrants against Russia or Israel?

Dale M has an answer that addresses the jurisdictional issue. Assuming, without considering myself, that jurisdiction is present to issue the warrant, why issue them against people in a country that will not enforce it?
Because it operates as a de facto travel ban for anyone with a warrant outstanding that wants to travel to a place where the warrant would be enforced.
